# python csv check url status and write result in same row

Tags: python, csv, row

I wrote a script to check the status of the url. I want the result in the same row as the url in my csv.
For example:

https//www.test1.com, 200
https//www.test2.com,  404

Unfortunately my script writes the results in new rows below, like this:

https//www.test1.com
https//www.test2.com
200
404

```
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd    
#from IPython.testing.decorators import skip

results = []
with open('module.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        results.append(row[2])

for url in results:   
    try:
        response= requests.head(url)   
        status= str(response.status_code)   
  
        print(url + "," + status)
        results.append(status)

        except Exception:  
        pd.Series(list(results)).to_csv("status_code_list.csv", index=False)
```

Any ideas how to fix that? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: results.append is just adding an entry (a response code) to something that is already a list (of URLs). Thus, you still have a 1-dimentional collection.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are appending the status codes to your original results list. Try the following

```
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd    
#from IPython.testing.decorators import skip

results = []
with open('module.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        results.append(row[2])

new_results = []
for url in results:   
    try:
        response= requests.head(url)   
        status= str(response.status_code)   
  
        new_results.append(url + "," + status)
        #results.append(status)

    except Exception:
        pass
pd.Series(list(new_results)).to_csv("status_code_list.csv", index=False)
```